# How can I play the League of Legend in Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)?

Tags: 15.04, wine, games, playonlinux

I just learned to install League of Legends in Ubuntu, and there are several problems.

First, the update takes a long time, which could be attributed to my net work. Anyway, it can be done after spending a long time, so this is not a real problem.

Second, there is problem of the in-game store (the game crash everytime I try buy items). To solve this problem, I followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/League_of_Legends. However, when I use the **LoL-Linux-Tools** to execute the **Texture Patch**, it works for a while, but if I relaunch the Client, it says something about "detect possible data corruption" then I have to update the patch (I believe what it did is to erase the changes done by the **LoL-Linux-Tools**). As a result, the in-game store is not working again.

As suggested by the website, I also "edit the .../Config/Game.cfg and under the [General] section add "x3d_platform=1"". And what I got is a functional in-game store, with "blurry textures".

Do I need to wait for the latest version of LOL available in the "PlayOnLinux"?

Comment: And I reinstall again through ""PlayOnLinux"", then I try the custom mode. What happen is when ever I press the "win" or "Alt" key, the game will freeze and takes me time to get out of the frozen screen...

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnLinux seems to be a bit outdated, see if this is any help:

https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends